# Confused on the css name

Tags: html, css

css:

```
.a .b { position: relative; }
.c { position: relative; }
```

Then I though it would work the same way if I wrote it like this:

`.a .b .c { position: relative; }`

however, it doesn't, it has no effect about `.c`. So why it's not working when I put them together?

Comment: `.a .b` means ".b. that are *children* of .a".  `.a,.b` means "either .a *or* .b".

Answer (score 5):

what you want is

```
.a .b, .c { position: relative; }
```

`.a .b .c` expects this

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="c"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

having a comma means `.a .b` OR `.c`

Comment: `<div class="a b"></div><div class="c"></div>` I guess it will also work for this?

Comment: no, that would be `.a.b, .c`  note that I removed the space between `.a` and `.b` with a space means b will be a child of a. No space means the element will have BOTH a and b

Comment: I don't want to come off as pedantic, but you should read [a tutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/) first, before writing code you don't understand and then asking questions until it happens to work.